# Change a property of one object in an array of objects using setState (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, filter

My state is an array of objects representing books.  Each book has a number of properties, including a "shelf" property, and an "id".  The books are displayed according to the shelf property's setting: currentlyReading, wantToRead, or read.

Each book has a drop-down select that to allow the user to change the shelf setting.  I have an event handler set up, which passes the new shelf and the book id.

With the setState call, I am trying to 1) isolate the particular book using the passed-in id property, then 2) change the shelf property of that book to the new one selected by the user, then 3) re-render with the new shelf, which should place the book in the new shelf.  I am isolating the correct book by calling filter on the array, but after that I am getting lost.  The code is below (JS first, then the JSX with the drop-down).  How can I accomplish this, I tried several approaches, including passing in prevState.  The latest one below is from an example I tried to emulate from reactTraining but it is giving me a Syntax error: Unexpected token in the setState call.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        books: []
    }
};

componentDidMount() {
    getAll().then((books) => {
        this.setState({ books })
    })
}

onSelectChange = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.name
    const newShelf = e.target.value
    console.log(id, newShelf)
    let changeShelf = this.state.books.filter((book) => { return 
        book.id === id})

    this.setState({
        changeShelf[0].shelf: changeShelf[0].newShelf
    })
}

<li key={book.id}>
    <div className="book">
        <div className="book-top">
            <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 
                193, backgroundImage: `url("${ 
                book.imageLinks.thumbnail 
                }")` }}>
            </div>
            <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                <select name={book.id} onChange={onSelect}>
                    <option value="none" disabled>Move to...</option>
                    <option value="currentlyReading">Currently 
                        Reading</option>
                    <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
                    <option value="read">Read</option>
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
        <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a loop through the books. When you find the book with the id, just change the shelf property:

```
onSelectChange = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.name
    const newShelf = e.target.value
    console.log(id, newShelf)
    const books = this.state.books.slice(); // Create local copy to change.
    books.forEach((book) => {
      if (book.id === id) {
        book.shelf = newShelf;
      }
    });
    this.setState({ books });
}
```

Comment: This worked, and I see why you need to create a local copy and change it, then swap it in.  But I have one question - while I understand why the forEach loop works, why did you need to do the slice first? – HughB

Comment: the slice is used to make a local non-mutable copy of the state array.https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/